# how can I make my mouse look like a pointer icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a space shooter in which you fly through the galaxy and you need to shoot at enemy ships. I made this using HTMl, CSS and JS.

Now I want to make my cursor look like this pointer cross: https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miscellaneous-icons-3/200/pointer_cross_aim-512.png.

Does anybody have a clue how I can do this using HTML,CSS and JS? I have already been looking around but couldn't find what I was looking for but on this site I was referred to calenders for some reason.

Thanks in advance already.

Answer (score 3):

Like so:

```css
.custom {
  cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto;
}
```

The url should ofcourse match the path to your image.

source: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/